# Overhead of any react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

Context: We have a theme context provider which passes down a theme to all our children. The theme is calculated basis the device's dimensions. We can easily extract the values out of this theme using `useTheme` hook at any component.

Also, we have a constants file where we generate our theme and export the above values.

So in our React codebase we have to two ways to get theme properties. Either using the `useTheme` hook or importing the constants from the constants file.

I am assuming that using the constant will be computationally efficient because react hooks are special functions (with their special rules) and there must be some overhead to them. Can anyone clarify which is the better approach and overall what overhead do react hooks add?

Comment: Overhead in what manner? Sounds like premature optimizations

Comment: If we have 1000s component running a function again and again and checking it for some rule, which can be avoided. Will it not save something?

Comment: `Also, we have a constants file where we generate our theme and export the above values.` I don't think we can do this, we can only use a function to generate this file. A hook `useTheme` is good.

Comment: We can do it. The values we pass to our theme in `ThemeProvideder` are coming from some generator function right. The same value from generator function is used exported in our constants

Answer (score 0):

Your use case description indeed matches the `useContext` hook.

> using the constant will be computationally efficient because react hooks are special functions (with their special rules) and there must be some overhead to them.

While there is indeed definitely some overhead involved with React hooks, it is usually negligible.

As stated above, your use case is very common, it even matches the situation of React styling libraries, like `styled-components` mentioned in your tags: plenty applications use them, some very probably with thousands of mounted components, and they still use them without issue.

> which is the better approach

As always, there is no definitive "better", only better match to some situation and requirements.

If you are sure all your project will use your constants file only, and your components will never be used in another place with another context (different theme), then direct file import is fine.

`useContext` is a form of inversion of control pattern: you no longer directly import the dependency (your theme), it is the framework that provides it. That way, you can easily swap it, whether due to project change, or in runtime, or depending on where you are in the application: you gain an extra level of flexibility.